# Column chart not updating if a column value decreases

Tags: android, scichart

If the values in a Column chart increases the column chart updates and everything looks good. But when the value decreases columns are not updated and it still displays the old values.

```
private fun drawColumnChart() {
    UpdateSuspender.using(lineChart) {
        lineChart.theme = R.style.SciChart_Bright_Spark
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.renderableSeries, rSeries)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.chartModifiers, sciChartBuilder
                .newModifierGroupWithDefaultModifiers().build())
        sciChartBuilder.newAnimator(rSeries)
                .withWaveTransformation()
                .withInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
                .withDuration(3000)
                .withStartDelay(350)
                .start()
    }
}

private fun createDataSeries(values: Array<Int>): IXyDataSeries<Int, Int> {
    val dataSeries: IXyDataSeries<Int, Int> = sciChartBuilder
            .newXyDataSeries(Int::class.javaObjectType, Int::class.javaObjectType).build()
    for (i in values.indices) {
        dataSeries.append(i, values[i])
    }
    return dataSeries;
}

private fun createRSeries(values: Array<Int>): FastColumnRenderableSeries {

    val dataSeries: IXyDataSeries<Int, Int> = createDataSeries(values)

    return sciChartBuilder.newColumnSeries()
            .withStrokeStyle(-0xdcdcdd, 0.4f)
            .withDataPointWidth(0.5)
            .withDataSeries(dataSeries)
            .withPaletteProvider(ColumnsPaletteProvider())
            .build()
}

private fun createXandYAxis() {
    xAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis()
            .withGrowBy(0.2, 0.2)
            .withLabelProvider(YearsLabelProvider())
            .build()
    yAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis()
            .withAutoRangeMode(AutoRange.Always).build()
    Collections.addAll(lineChart.xAxes, xAxis)
    Collections.addAll(lineChart.yAxes, yAxis)
}
```

- Example 1: DataSet (A= 50, B=60, C=20) these values are displayed correctly
- Example 2: DataSet (A= 80, B=60, C=20) A increased from 50 to 80 in this DataSet: these values are displayed correctly as well.
- Example 3: DataSet (A= 14, B=60, C=20) notice A decreased from 80 to 14 the graph is not refreshed and the old value of A= 80 is displayed

**Update**
The values of Column chart is updated in the listener of donut chart

```
segments.forEach(Consumer { segment: PieSegment ->
        segment.addIsSelectedChangeListener {
            var chartData  = dataCollector(it.value.toLong())
            vehicleData[0] = chartData.fuels
            vehicleData[1] = chartData.repairs
            vehicleData[2] = chartData.tolls
            vehicleData[3] = chartData.mis

            rSeries = createRSeries(vehicleData)
            drawColumnChart()

        }
    })
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of data set or full code which reproduces this problem, because I'm not sure what do you mean by increasing/decreasing of column values? Can you clarify this part?

Comment: @YuraKhariton updated the question with example of data set

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how you update your column values. Are you creating new colum series for each data set? I'm looking on your code and there is only append() calls which add new point into the end of data series. There is now update() calls in your example

Comment: @YuraKhariton updated the question. I update the column chart values in the listener of Donut chart. As in the examples Example1 and Example2 works fine, since the values are increasing. But Example 3 doesn't since the value is decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're adding new column series on top of the old one, because RenderableCollection isn't cleared before you add new column series. I would suggest to add clear() call for renderable series collection into drawColumnChart().

```
private fun drawColumnChart() {
    UpdateSuspender.using(lineChart) {
        animator?.cancel() // cancel if there is animation in progress

        lineChart.renderableSeries.clear()
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.renderableSeries, rSeries)

        animator = sciChartBuilder.newAnimator(rSeries)
                    .withWaveTransformation()
                    .withInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .withDuration(3000)
                    .withStartDelay(350).build()

        animator.start()
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest to set theme and modifiers once, because in case if you leave that code in drawColumnChart() you'll need to clear modifier collection as well + you'll reset theme every time column is rerendered:

```
private fun createXandYAxis() {
    xAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis()
        .withGrowBy(0.2, 0.2)
        .withLabelProvider(YearsLabelProvider())
        .build()
    yAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis()
        .withAutoRangeMode(AutoRange.Always).build()

    UpdateSuspender.using(lineChart) {
        lineChart.theme = R.style.SciChart_Bright_Spark

        Collections.addAll(lineChart.xAxes, xAxis)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.yAxes, yAxis)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.chartModifiers, sciChartBuilder
            .newModifierGroupWithDefaultModifiers().build())
    }

}
```

Comment: I did implement the above code. For the first time the ColumnChart is rendered. While rendering it again with different values, it fails with NPE

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries.data.XSeriesRenderPassData.isValid()' on a null object reference
        at com.scichart.charting.visuals.animations.WaveTransformationBase.onAnimationStart(SourceFile:106)

Comment: This probably is caused by unfinished animation for series, that you removed from series collection. This means that you need to store Animator somewhere and before you remove series cancel animation.